# Задача: Циклы. И мои большие проблемы

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while

Сидел тут, и решил порешать задачки по Python (PS Задачки на Английском, мне помогал Google Translator). В задачках нужно просто исправить код. Остановился на циклах.. и нашлась такая, которую я не понял. Там есть подсказки, я понял все кроме 1-й.

Задание: Заполните пробелы, чтобы функция `print_prime_factors` распечатала все простые множители числа. Простой делитель - это простое число, которое делит другое без остатка. (Fill in the blanks to make the `print_prime_factors` function print all the prime factors of a number. A prime factor is a number that is prime and divides another without a remainder.)

Данный мне код на исправление:

```py
def print_prime_factors(number):
  # Начните с двух, это первое простое число. (Start with two, which is the first prime)
  factor = ___ #Поставил тут 2
  # Keep going until the factor is larger than the number
  while factor <= number:
    # Проверьте, является ли factor делителем числа (Check if factor is a divisor of number)
    if number % factor == ___: #?
      # If it is, print it and divide the original number
      print(factor)
      number = number / factor
    else:
      # Если это не так, увеличьте factor на единицу (If it's not, increment the factor by one)
      ___ #factor += 1
  return "Done"

print_prime_factors(100)
# Should print 2,2,5,5
# DO NOT DELETE THIS COMMENT
```

В моих комментах (они напротив _____) поставил то, что написано в комментах выше (Подсказки). Там где проблема, я написал #?, нет никаких мыслей что делать..

Что прикажете, как быть?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if number % factor == 0:
```

здесь идёт проверка делится ли `number` на `factor` без остатка